# shields.io appveyor badge not working

Tags: node.js, npm, appveyor, shields.io

This is what I want but for my repo:

[image]

https://img.shields.io/appveyor/ci/shelljs/shelljs/master.svg?style=flat-square&label=windows

But my repo gives:

https://img.shields.io/appveyor/ci/danday74/shelljs.exec/master.svg?style=flat-square&label=windows

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I can use an appveyor badge directly without shields but I want the shields badge look.

This is the unwanted but working appveyor direct badge link:

https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/status/lo4n79qp3jb0j4wo?svg=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't like the dot in the project name. Had to change it to a hyphen. The working URL is:

https://img.shields.io/appveyor/ci/danday74/shelljs-exec/master.svg?style=flat-square&label=windows